# SQL : how to check value used in other table?

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE sectors
(
    name varchar,
    id integer,
    capacity integer
)

CREATE TABLE employees
(
    id integer,
    for_sector_id integer,
    name varchar
)
```

Here I need to check if entered `for_sector_id` is whether null or already using in data of sectors. Thought about adding check clause down by create script:

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(
    ...
    CHECK(for_sector_id is null or for_sector_id in sectors.id)
)
```

May this solve the problem?

Comment: Hi @johbosch please can you tell us what database do you use ? Oracle, MySQL, SQLServer or something else... ? Thanks!

Comment: Use a foreign key

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to check that the reference is valid then you can use a foreign key reference:

```
CREATE TABLE sectors (
    id integer primary key,
    name varchar,
    capacity integer
);

CREATE TABLE employees (
    id integer,
    for_sector_id integer,
    name varchar(255),  -- you want a length in most databases
    foreign key for_sector_id references sector(id)        
);
```

The referenced id needs to be a primary or unique key.

EDIT:

I originally misunderstood the question.  I thought the sector needed to be "marked as used" in the `sector` table to be valid (say by having `capacity > 0`).  The OP appears to merely want its existence in the table.

For this situation, I can think of three options if you want a "conditional" foreign key reference (i.e. there is a used flag or say, `capacity > 0`):

1. A trigger
2. A user-defined function for the `check` constraint
3. A funky foreign key relationship that uses a computed column

Not all databases support all of these.  (As I write this, you haven't specified the database, so I'm only answering the question that you have explicitly asked and not elaborating.)

Comment: Why would a computed column be needed? this seems like a standard foreign key from employees to sectors

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I don't know of any database that supports filtered foreign key references.  I don't even think Postgres supports foreign keys to inherited tables, which would be another solution.

Comment: What do you mean with "filtered" foreign key? It seems like a plain nullable column that references the sectors table

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I misunderstood the question and changed the answer.  I left the original answer in the edited portion.  I thought "used" was an attribute of `sector` and only `used` sectors could be referenced.  My misinterpretation.